# How to read from a file to a map

Tags: c++11

I have a text file that looks like that:

```
a  
00000000  
00011100  
00010000  
00010000  
00000100  
00000000  
11110000  
00000000  
z  
00000000  
00011100  
00000000  
01100000  
01000100  
00000000  
00000000  
00110000   
t  
001....  

and so on...
```

and i want to read this file in map of `std::map <char,std::bitset<8>[8]> table;`
I know how to read from a file but reading from file to this map troubles me really. 
I tried to read the file in a `std::vector<char>` and from that copy the literal one at a time to a char and the bits to a `std::bitset<8> a[8];` but inserting this to the map does not work. Is there a option to read the file and insert it directly in the map?

Answer (score 0):

Does not contain any error chcking.

```
std::istream& str = std::cin;
std::map<char, std::array<std::bitset<8>, 8>> map;

std::string ch;
while (std::getline(str, ch))
{
    std::array<std::bitset<8>, 8> bitset;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        std::string line;
        str >> line;
        bitset[i] = std::bitset<8>(line);
    }
    map[ch[0]] = std::move(bitset);
    str.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```